# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, sql, string

I checked my code over and over. But i cant seem to find where this error occurs. 
Here is my code:

```
public static string MerchantUpdate(string firstN, string lastN, int type, int reseller, string CoName, string site, int industry, bool isact, bool isdel, string houseNO, string street, string town, string city, string state, string zipcode, int countryID, string telephone, string fax, string userN, string emailA, string secQ, string secA, decimal set, decimal month, decimal dep, decimal with, decimal eTrans, decimal acct, DateTime created)
{
        string retmerUpdate = "";

        string merUpdate = "UPDATE MerchantMaster SET FirstName = @fname, LastName = @lname, MerchantTypeID = @typeID, ResellerMasterID = @resellerID, "
                         + "CompanyName = @CoName, Url = @url, IndustryID = @IndustryID, IsActive = @isact, IsDeleted = @isdel, HouseNo = hnumber, "
                         + "StreetAddress = @address, Town = @townAD, City = @cityAD, State = @stateAD, ZipCode = @zipC, CountryID = @countryID, "
                         + "TelephoneNo = @teleNo, FaxNo = @faxNo, UserName = @uName, EmailAdr = @eAD, SecurityQ = @secQ, SecurityA = @secA, Setup = @set, "
                         + "Monthly = @month, Deposit = @dep, Withdraw = @with, EmailTransfer = @eTrans, AccTransfer = @acct, DateCreated = @created WHERE id = @id";

        string[] param = { "@fname", "@lname", "@typeID", "@resellerID", "@CoName", "@url", "@IndustryID", "@isact", "@isdel", "@hnumber", "@address", "@townAD", "@cityAD", "@stateAD", "@zipC", "@countryID", "@teleNo", "@faxNo", "@uName", "@eAD", "@secQ", "@secA", "@set", "@month", "@dep", "@with", "@eTrans", "@acct", "@created" };
        object[] paramVal = { firstN, lastN, type, reseller, CoName, site, industry, isact, isdel, houseNO, street, town, city, state, zipcode, countryID, telephone, fax, userN, emailA, secQ, secA, set, month, dep, with, eTrans, acct, created};

        try
        {
            ClassDBQuery.ExecNonQuery(merUpdate, param, paramVal);
            retmerUpdate = "success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retmerUpdate = ex.Message;
        }

        return retmerUpdate;
 }
```

Here is my code behind:

```
 using (SqlConnection connectString = new SqlConnection(GetConnectString()))

 //update merchant master
 try
 {
    int idses = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());

    string merUpdate = ClassMerchant.MerchantUpdate(fName.Text, lName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ddlT.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlR.SelectedValue), CompName.Text, website.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ddlI.SelectedValue), true, false, houseN.Text, streetAD.Text, townAD.Text, cityAD.Text, stateAD.Text, zipC.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ddlC.SelectedValue), teleNumb.Text, faxNumb.Text, userN.Text, Eaddress.Text, secQuest.Text, secAns.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(set.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(month.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(dep.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(with.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(etrans.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(aTrans.Text), DateTime.Now);

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
 }
 finally
 {
     if (connectString.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        connectString.Close();
 }
```

Please help me.

Comment: what is the erro and in which line u get it...

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format..this is the error i keep on getting...i get the error in the "string merUpdate" line... @voo

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format..this is the error i keep on getting...i get the error in the "string merUpdate" line... @amit Singh

Comment: i checked your string merupdate it work perfect it not problem there

Comment: i have a dropdown list databind..
void GetCountry()
        {
            DataTable DTcountry = new DataTable();
            DTcountry = ClassMerchant.GetCountry();

            ddlC.DataSource = DTcountry;
            ddlC.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            //ddlC.DataValueField = "CountryID";
            ddlC.DataBind();
            ddlC.Items.Insert(0, "Choose Country");
        } // end GetCountry

when i remove the commnet for the datavaluefield i get this error:
selectedvalue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items dropdownlist

Comment: what is ur real question i can not understand.....

Comment: im sorry..
i found out why keep on getting the error..in my code, i binded a dropdown list..here is my code

DataTable DTcountry = new DataTable();
DTcountry = ClassMerchant.GetCountry();
ddlC.DataSource = DTcountry;
ddlC.DataTextField = "CountryName";
//ddlC.DataValueField = "CountryID";
ddlC.DataBind();
ddlC.Items.Insert(0, "Choose Country");

when i remove the at .datavaluefield, i get this error: selectedvalue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items dropdownlist

but my databind for dropdown list works fine in my registration page..

Answer (score 0):

hnumber is missing @ in front of it

Comment: You define @id in the query but you are not passing anything for it

Comment: i included @id..but i still get the same error...if this helps, it doesn't go to the data layer when i am debugging it...

Comment: I do not see any other problem in your syntax but my suggestion would be to remove inline sql and write a stored procedure instead. Writing inline sql in code is not considered good practice, it makes your code less readable and harder to troubleshoot.

Comment: i found the error...its in my databing for dropdown list...
here is my code for the dropdown list:
void GetCountry()
        {
            DataTable DTcountry = new DataTable();
            DTcountry = ClassMerchant.GetCountry();

            ddlC.DataSource = DTcountry;
            ddlC.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            ddlC.DataValueField = "CountryID";
            ddlC.DataBind();
            ddlC.Items.Insert(0, "Choose Country");
        } // end GetCountry

but i get this error: selectedvalue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items dropdownlist

Comment: Good. Maybe post what you find separately and accept it as correct answer? That way people will see.. Also, please consider removing inline sql in the near future.